# Database server with high CPU usgae

Tags: sql, database, performance, sql-server-2008, cpu

I have a very strong server containing 32GB RAM DDR3, 8 cores (Dual Quad), 4 TB HDD and I am running SQL Server R2 Web Edition.

We have huge activity in this DB and using a profiler, I've seen we have nearly 600,000 transactions/queries to it.

The CPU usage is crazy, going from 30% to 90%, up and down, and I have no idea how I can track what is the cause. I've seen some heavy queries, but solved it, now I cant see anything that should make it load this way, every table is indexed and I let another colleague work on the DB and he said he doesnt get where it comes from too.

We have 1GBIT uplink so its not a network issue as well.

I thought maybe its because Web Edition is limited to work with so many transactions? the main reason why I dont upgrade is becuase of low budget to that project.

Any suggestions? ideas? something?..

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are queries slow?

Comment: Actually there's no specific problem besides the fact that we are about to grow up, so if the high cpu is becuase of the high amount of queries, it will get 100% soon I guess...

Answer (score 0):

you can try spanning the database file across multiple files on multiple disks

Comment: I've checked the process monitor and I am not sure its a I/O issue. would you suggest that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Check your application using performance monitor to see our your application make use of CPU usage, poor application can affect CPU status.